# Webpacker packs in rails 6 understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, webpacker

I am relatively new to rails and got stuck in webpacker entry points. Now I have worked with asset pipeline and thoroughly understand the concept of it. But When I started learning wepacker, I got little confused.
The first issue is while referencing our javascript file while using asset pipeline, we use **javascript_include_tag** and give it a name. It can be application.js file or any other file name that is under **app/assets/javascripts** folder. And If it is nested in this folder as well, then we give it relative path which works.
My issue is Webpacker has a concept of entry points which are in **app/javascript/packs**, we include it in our views or layout files by using **javascript_pack_tag** and give further the name of the pack. But If I have other files in this directory lets say I have app.javascript/custom/custom_js_file.js. How should I reference this in my view.
When I try to reference this in my view using javascript_pack_tag 'custom/custom_js_file', it gets me manifest error that It can't find any entry points. How to resolve this issue.
Should I create separate packs and include them in my packs or what??
This was my first question. My second Question is Asset pipeline does three things.
Minification, Concatenation and pre-compilation pre-processing, Does Webpacker does the same ???

By the way, thank you for reading such a long discription.

Comment: It's not much of an answer, but I strongly recommend upgrading to https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker